# Kiddush on Grape Juice Jello

Tags: halacha-theory, grapes-wine, kiddush

May one use grape juice or wine that was turned into Jello for Kiddush? Does concentration matter, for example, if the cup was already full of wine, and a bit of jello was added?

I saw a related question here, but it was talking about frozen grape juice: [Bracha on frozen grape juice](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/bracha-on-frozen-grape-juice)